# Can I used HDFS mv on encrypted folders

Tags: encryption, hdfs, mv

I need to load hive partitions from staging folders. Currently we copy and delete. Can I use mv? 
I am told that I can not use mv if the folders are EAR (Encryption At Rest). How to tell if a folder is EAR'ed?

Comment: This is a Cloudera 5.14 cluster and we have Apache Sentry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the feature you are using for encryption at rest is HDFS transparent encryption (see [cloudera 5.14 docs](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/cdh_sg_hdfs_encryption.html)).

There is a command to get all the zones configured for encryption, [`listZones`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/TransparentEncryption.html#listZones), but that command requires admin privileges. However, if you just need to check the permission of one file at a time, you should be able to run [`getFileEncryptionInfo`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/TransparentEncryption.html#getFileEncryptionInfo) without these permissions.

For example

```
hdfs crypto -getFileEncryptionInfo -path /path/to/my/file
```

As for whether you can move files, it looks like the answer to that is no. From [the "Rename and Trash considerations" section of the transparent encryption documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/TransparentEncryption.html#Rename_and_Trash_considerations):

> HDFS restricts file and directory renames across encryption zone boundaries. This includes renaming an encrypted file / directory into an unencrypted directory (e.g., `hdfs dfs mv /zone/encryptedFile /home/bob`), renaming an unencrypted file or directory into an encryption zone (e.g., `hdfs dfs mv /home/bob/unEncryptedFile /zone`), and renaming between two different encryption zones (e.g., `hdfs dfs mv /home/alice/zone1/foo /home/alice/zone2`).

and

> A rename is only allowed if the source and destination paths are in the same encryption zone, or both paths are unencrypted (not in any encryption zone).

So it looks like using `cp` and `rm` is your best bet.